# algorithm to stack items in a pyramid shape?

Tags: actionscript-3, algorithm, graphics, loops

How do I stack items in a pyramid (as opposed to say, a grid) using actionscript 3.0?

The shapes are irregular so I only need an approximate pyramid shape...

It's for a 2D pyramid.

Comment: What items.Do you mean 3D models?

Comment: The bottom of the piramid holds the most items,and the items decremnt while coming to the the top where is only one item.That's a 2D Piramid(or a triangle if you'd like it that way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to visualise a set of items in a pyramid shape
you do it almost like visualising a grid, 
just shrinking the boundaries of the inner loop.

```
for (i = 0; i<smth1; i+=1) {
    for (j = i; j<smth2-i; j+=1) {
        // ...use i, j as multipliers for coordinates
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var size:uint = 21;
var space:uint = 10;

graphics.lineStyle(10);
var i:uint, j:uint;
var px:uint, py:uint;
for (i = 0; i<size; i+=1) {
    for (j = i; j<size-i; j+=1) {
        px = i*space;
        py = j*space;
        graphics.moveTo(px, py);
        graphics.lineTo(px+1, py+1);
    }
}
```

If you use i for x and j for y, you get a right-pointing pyramid shape.
If you use j for x and i for y, you get a down-pointing pyramid shape.
If you subtract i or j from the size, you reverse the direction.

You may want to use different spacing for x and y.

Only the inner loop scales your pyramid.